# È corretto dire “che ti serva di lezione”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Discutendo con mio figlio su un esercizio di italiano che riporta la frase

> Che ti serva **di** lezione

io ho obiettato che si dovrebbe dire invece

> Che ti serva **da** lezione

Quale delle due è corretta? Sono ammissibili entrambe?

Comment: Io in Toscana ho sempre detto :-che ti serva di lezione-

Comment: @AnnaliseAmbrogio Questo non è un forum e le risposte dovrebbero essere più motivate. In ogni caso, ti do il benvenuto!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=serva%20da%20lezione%2Cserva%20da%20esempio%2C%20serva%20di%20lezione%2C%20serva%20di%20esempio%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cserva%20da%20lezione%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserva%20da%20esempio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserva%20di%20lezione%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserva%20di%20esempio%3B%2Cc0://) mostra  entrambi  gli usi.

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/servire/) sembra suggerire l’uso della preposizione ***di***:

> il viaggio mi è servito di riposo, di svago; servire di esempio, di modello; le serva di norma, di avviso, di ammaestramento.

Comment: In alcuni degli esempi citati (non tutti) il "di" mi suona strano "a orecchio" ma probabilmente è una questione anche di abitudine della lingua parlata. In caso di dubbi si potrebbe utilizzare "_come_"

Answer (score 0):

Sempre da [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mettere_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> [far subire a qualcuno una
> punizione che serva da ammaestramento] ≈ (fam.) aggiustare, castigare, dare una lezione

"Che ti serva da lezione" è corretto.

Comment: Puoi indicare che cosa stai citando di preciso dalla Treccani, per favore?

Comment: In tutta quella pagina non viene mai menzionata la locuzione “servire da/di lezione”. Sì si parla di “servire da ammaestramento”, ma questo non dice niente sulla locuzione della domanda (e tanto meno sulla sua versione con “di”).

Answer (score 0):

I due costrutti di "servire", con "di" o con "da" sono entrambi legittimi e l'opzione è in generale indifferente.

Comment: Accademia della crusca

Comment: Puoi fornire una fonte più precisa (a una specifica pagina web, libro, articolo), per piacere?

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE! Questo post è apparso nella coda di revisione di "low quality posts". Quindi, potresti aggiungere le fonti della tua affermazione?